# Should I be using static classes or something other than structs?

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, static, filter, struct

I needed a way to add filters to a page like so:

> Catalog/Size-Medium/Color-Red/

I have a set amount of filters and they contain properties which are very unlikely to change anytime soon. To process these filters I decided on enums, but this turned very insidious as I needed to incorporate nulls, extension methods, and other properties.

Finally I came across this [Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2907408/1347514) which suggested using structs. Here is an example of one I've incorporated:

```
    public struct Color
{
    private int id;
    private bool isDef;

    private Color(int value) { id = value; isDef = true; }
    public bool Hasvalue { get { return isDef; } }
    public bool IsNull { get { return !isDef; } }

    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            switch(id)
            {
                case 0: return "None";
                case 1: return "Black";
                case 2: return "Blue";
                case 3: return "Green";
                case 4: return "Orange";
                case 5: return "Pink";
                case 6: return "Brown";
                case 7: return "White";
                case 8: return "Yellow";
                case 9: return "Gray";
                case 10: return "Purple";
                case 11: return "Red";
                default: return null;
            }
        }
    }

    public string Abbreviation
    {
        get
        {
            switch(id)
            {
                case 1: return "BK";
                case 2: return "BL";
                case 3: return "GR";
                case 4: return "OR";
                case 5: return "PK";
                case 6: return "BN";
                case 7: return "WT";
                case 8: return "YL";
                case 9: return "GY";
                case 10: return "PR";
                case 11: return "RD";
                default: return null;
            }
        }
    }

    public static IEnumerable<Color> GetValues()
    {
        yield return Color.None;
        yield return Color.Black;
        yield return Color.Blue;
        yield return Color.Green;
        yield return Color.Orange;
        yield return Color.Pink;
        yield return Color.Brown;
        yield return Color.White;
        yield return Color.Yellow;
        yield return Color.Gray;
        yield return Color.Purple;
        yield return Color.Red;
    }

    public static Color Parse(string value)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
            return Color.None;
        foreach (var c in GetValues())
        {
            if (String.Equals(c.Name, value, StringComparison.Ordinal))
                return c;
        }
        return Color.None;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if(!(obj is Color))
            return false;
        Color color = (Color)obj;
        return color.Name.Equals(this.Name, StringComparison.Ordinal);
    }

    public static Color None = new Color(0);
    public static Color Black = new Color(1);
    public static Color Blue = new Color(2);
    public static Color Green = new Color(3);
    public static Color Orange = new Color(4);
    public static Color Pink = new Color(5);
    public static Color Brown = new Color(6);
    public static Color White = new Color(7);
    public static Color Yellow = new Color(8);
    public static Color Gray = new Color(9);
    public static Color Purple = new Color(10);
    public static Color Red = new Color(11);
}
```

These work well but they just don't feel correct in some way. For example, I'm having to write the same code for each struct, which seems like a lot of code. It would be so much easier to inherit reusable code, and to constrict the data to interfaces somehow.

Is there a better way of doing this? I've tried using Static Classes but couldn't get my head around how to build one with similar functionality to my struct.

Sorry if I seem hopeless at posting, it's my first time.

Comment: You struct is ok (small and  immutable, also missing GetHashCode and ==). But it looks like you have problem with some other code that you did not show, so it is hard to suggest anything. Note that you can safely cut 90% of code in this Color to post in the question.

Comment: Can you show us the filter code, please. By the way, why are you not using `System.Drawing.Color`?

Comment: I think my wording led to confusion. My filter code is fine. The part about writing a lot of the same code was in reference the structs themselves. Writing 6 long structs with almost identical code seemed a bit inefficient.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes Good point about the System.Drawing.Color. The only missing piece is the not-found value. Also, it might be better to change the type of the enum to 'byte' and set explicit hex values to make it possible to expose a 'public byte GetHex(Colors color)' method.

Comment: The `System.Drawing.Color` struct has also `Color.Transparent` and  `Color.Empty` colors, which be used as "not found".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You'll want an enum for the colors and a dictionary for the apprev-color mapping**

**Start with the correct class import:**

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
```

**Create an enum containing all of the possible colors:**

```
enum Colors : uint 
{
  Black =  0x00000000,
  Blue =   0x0000FF00,
  Green =  0x00FF0000,
  Orange = 0xFFA50000,
  Pink =   0xFFC0CB00,
  Brown =  0xA52A2A00,
  White =  0xFFFFFF00,
  Yellow = 0xFFFF0000,
  Gray =   0x80808000,
  Purple = 0x80008000,
  Red =    0xFF000000
};
```

*Note: This is assuming RGBA [rrggbbaa] where or Red|Green|Blue|Alpha can be any value from 00-FF (0-255).*

**Then use a dictionary for to map the 1-many relationship of colors-values:**

```
private Dictionary<string, Colors> colorMap = new Dictionary<string, Colors>();
colorMap.Add("None", Colors.None);
colorMap.Add("Black", Colors.Black);
colorMap.Add("BK", Colors.Black);
colorMap.Add("Blue", Colors.Blue);
colorMap.Add("BL", Colors.Blue);
colorMap.Add("Green", Colors.Green);
colorMap.Add("GR", Colors.Green);
colorMap.Add("Orange", Colors.Orange);
colorMap.Add("OR", Colors.Orange);
colorMap.Add("Pink", Colors.Pink);
colorMap.Add("PK", Colors.Pink);
colorMap.Add("Brown", Colors.Brown);
colorMap.Add("BN", Colors.Brown);
colorMap.Add("White", Colors.White);
colorMap.Add("WT", Colors.White);
colorMap.Add("Yellow", Colors.Yellow);
colorMap.Add("YL", Colors.Yellow);
colorMap.Add("Gray", Colors.Gray);
colorMap.Add("Grey", Colors.Gray);
colorMap.Add("GY", Colors.Gray);
colorMap.Add("Purple", Colors.Purple);
colorMap.Add("PR", Colors.Purple);
colorMap.Add("Red", Colors.Red);
colorMap.Add("RD", Colors.Red);
```

**And a dictionary lookup method for the mapping:**

```
public Color GetColor(string colorName)
{
  Color color = null;
  if (this.colormap.TryGetValue(colorName, out color));
  return color;
}
```

*Note: A property can't be used because you the input and output types are different.*

The [TryGetValue()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb347013.aspx) does a dictionary lookup. TryGetValue() is preferred over GetValue() because, if it fails to find the key it does nothing (defaulting to whatever you initially set the 'color' to. The alternative method (GetValue()) throws an exception on failure that would need to be caught.

**Bonus:**

I added another value to the mapping, see if you can find it. The benefit of mapping the values is, it's extensible (easy to add to). You don't lock yourself into a brittle structure.

**Disclaimer:**

I haven't written a line of C# in about a year so this code may not work exactly as posted. Hopefully, if there are any bugs, I did a good job of communicating the gist of what I mean.

**Update:**

I decided to add the RGBA values to the enum. If you didn't already know, at it's core an enum by default is like a 'dictionary' where the int is auto-generated. By changing it's type and defining the values it can be cast to a usable value ('dictionary' in this case).

**Getting the color name from the enum value is as simple as casting it:**

```
string colorName = "Gray";
Colors color = GetColor(colorName);
if(colorName != null)
{
  uint colorHex = (uint)color;
}
```

*Note: I would print colorHex but without proper formatting it'll just show the integer value (ie not the hex value). I can't remember how to do text formatting off the top of my head so I'm not going to bother. If somebody else wants to add string formatting I won't object.*

**Update 2: Reverse-Lookup**

```
public string GetAbbrev(Colors color)
{
  Dictionary<string, Colors> abbrev = this.colorMap.First(abbrev => abbrev.Value == color);
  return abbrev.Key;
}
```

I think this method should work for the reverse-lookup. If you don't understand the LINQ syntax, it's querying all the dictionary entries and returning the first one where the key matches the method's parameter. Then the key is returned from that entry.

Comment: That was kinda fun. It has been a while since I flexed my C# skills.

Comment: Interesting. I think the goal of your code is to obtain the hex code, when either a name or an abbreviation are given. How would you get the abbreviation for Color.Red or the name for Color.Brown? I guess I could keep adding dictionaries but that would do the same thing as my struct but in a seemingly less elegant way.

Comment: @Eco Not the goal but a useful side-effect. If you want the abbreviation you can search through the dictionary by values to find the matching key. Reverse-lookup will be O(n) complexity (ie vs normal lookup @ O(1)). You'd have to use dict.index() to grab the first value returned or return all the values that match a color because there is a 1-many relationship. 'I guess I could keep adding dictionaries,' no; unlike the code posted in the question, one map should handle all variations of abbrev-color mapping.

Comment: Oh I think I understand what you mean now. It's taking a bit as this is a new concept. Do you think you could post a sample of how you would do a reverse-lookup?

Comment: I already did. The GetAbbrev *is* the reverse lookup. It searches the dictionary by value and returns the key of the first match it finds.